# Variable and exponents trouble

Tags: python

Here is my code from what I have seen seen this should work, but it doesn't. I have little experience and would appreciate the help!!.

```
import math


print ("This is the exponent hub")

x = input("What is your base?")

y = input("What is the exponent?")

print (x)

print (y)

x**y
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What happens when you run this code and how does it differ from what you want?

Answer (score 2):

This is python, not C++. You may be failing to write the calculated number.
print(x**y)

Answer (score 2):

## Be careful.

There are important differences in how `input` works in Python2 and Python3

In Python2 you should use

```
x = int(raw_input(...))
```

or

```
x = float(raw_input(...))
```

or

```
from ast import literal_eval
x = literal_eval(raw_input(...))
```

**Although `x = input(...)` appears to work in Python2, it's really calling `eval()` which could cause the input to do bad things to your computer**

For Python3 you should use

```
x = int(input(...))
```

or

```
x = float(input(...))
```

or

```
from ast import literal_eval
x = literal_eval(input(...))
```

And similar for `y`. Otherwise you are trying to calculate the exponent of two strings!

Lastly, `(x**y)` calulates the result and discards it. You'll need to `print(x**y)`